# Angular router scroll, get position

Tags: angular, angular-router

In my main appComponent I have the following code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof Scroll)
    ).subscribe((res) => {
      const sEv = res as Scroll;
      console.log(sEv.position);
      this.scrollPosition = sEv.position ? sEv.position : [0, 0];
    });
  }
```

But everytime console log shows position as null. Why is this? Is it something wrong in my code?

Comment: you want only get current scroll position?

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent, true);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent, true);
  }

  scrollEvent = (event: any): void => {
    const number = event.srcElement.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
    console.log(number);
  }

Comment: event.srcElement.scrollingElement doesn't exist and document.scrollingElement .scrollTop return always 0

Comment: try ----event.srcElement.scrollTop----